# Is there a way to get R to spit out a tibble where it shows all the ecoregions for each species in this data set?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse, stringr, tibble

```
    Species    Ecoregions                                                        
   <fct>      <fct>                                                             
 1 acerifolia Central Corn Belt Plains                                          
 2 acerifolia Arkansas Valley                                                   
 3 acerifolia Ouachita Mountains                                                
 4 acutidens  Sonoran Desert                                                    
 5 acutidens  Southern and Baja California Pine-Oak Mountains                   
 6 acutidens  Mojave Basin and Range                                            
 7 acutidens  California Coastal Sage, Chaparral, and Oak Woodlands             
 8 acutifolia Sierra Madre Oriental with Conifer, Oak, and Mixed Forests        
 9 acutifolia Hills and Sierra with Low Tropical Deciduous Forest and Oak Forest
10 acutifolia Hills with Medium and High Evergreen Tropical Forest
```

If given a data set like the one listed above, is there anyway using either tidyverse or base r to get a tibble listing all of the ecoregions associated with each species? I figured there would be something in stringr for it, but I'm not sure how. For example:

```
   Species      Ecoregions
1 acerifolia    Central Corn Belt Plains, Arkansas Valley, Quachita Mountains
2 acutidens     Sonoran Desert, Southern and Baja California Pine-Oak Mountains, Mojave Basin and Range, etc.
```

Along those lines. Any advice or experience?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(Ecoregions = toString(unique(Ecoregions)))
```

`toString` is in base. You could also use `paste(..., collapse = ", ")`, or the `stringr` equivalent `stringr::str_c(..., collapse = ", ")`.